# Can't read float array into __m128

Tags: c, load, offset, sse, vectorization

I'm fiddling around with vectorization (first time learner). The point of it is the see whether I can unroll a loop. I like to load four consecutive floats like this, see Seg fault.

```
el0 = _mm_load_ps(&array[0]);
el1 = _mm_load_ps(&array[1]);   // Seg fault
```

I understand why I get the seg fault. My question is, is there a neat way of _mm_loading with an offset?

Comment: You're probably looking for unaligned [load intrinsics](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/cpp-mac/GUID-A3272CE8-E597-4296-AFE1-52BF12625F84.htm). `_mm_loadu_ps()` in particular.

Comment: You probably also want to stride through the array by 4 elements, not 1, assuming that the type of array is `float[]`.

Comment: Jason - Like I said the point is to unroll the loop, i.e. stride with higher than 1 element. The plan here is to see whether I can get speed up in some foo() calculations. The array elements I wanted to use is array[i], array[i+1] and array[i+2], or more specific, the four elements starting from i, i+1 and i+2.
Mystical - I guess I can muster a work around by tinkering with the functions you linked. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide full source code.

Answer (score 0):

commenters already solved it, but it's annoying when questions show up in the unanswered questions list.

```
_mm_load_ps(&array[0])   // load a vector of array[0..3]
_mm_load_ps(&array[1])   // load a vector of array[1..4].  different alignment than array[0]

// what you probably want is:
_mm_load_ps(&array[4])   // load a vector of array[4..7], aligned if array is aligned
```

Index stride should be `sizeof(vector_type)/sizeof(array[0])`.  (Then when you widen your code for AVX, you don't have to change the indexing.)